# movie where aliens invade a farm

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

- direct to video i believe
- 90s or 2000s
- real people, not animation.
- most action occurs at night
- may not be accurate, but i think the plot revolves around a family that gathers together for thanksgiving.
- i believe there was just one alien
- the alien attacks with a laser pointer-like gun. Said light generates terrible headaches on its target.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be [*Alien Abduction: Incident in Lake County*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Abduction:_Incident_in_Lake_County). It aired in 1998 on UPN and was a remake of an earlier 1989 "found footage" film, *[The McPherson Tape](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/The_McPherson_Tape)*. It's not animated. It involves the McPherson family joining for Thanksgiving dinner. The descriptions have a lot of bits about the lights being out, so I assume it's at night. It does have a ray-gun, but it burns people, and involves at least two aliens.