# Extraterrestrial TV Movie from the 70s or early 80s

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

If someone remembers a TV movie about a group of people, perhaps a family that are in a cabin but they are surrounded by extraterrestrials. 
UPDATE
I remember it wasn't a comedy it was a kind of horror tv movie or tele-theater. At the end the aliens get into de cabin or the house and their heads glow.
I think it was produced late 70´s or early 80s.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Rodrigo! See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some help getting more relevant details.

Comment: Hi!  This question needs more details before we can try to answer it.  Please [edit] anything else you can remember into the question.  Even what language it was in or what TV station you saw it on... anything.

Answer (score 4):

## *The Pod People* (1983); *MST3K* 3x03 (1991)

[*The Pod People*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pod_People) (also known as *Extra-Terrestrial Visitors*) began as a horror script about an alien terrorizing the members of a rock band trapped in a cabin in the woods.  Although "cute" elements — the friendship between a younger alien and a human child — were added to make the film resemble [*E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.T._the_Extra-Terrestrial) (1982), it retained the horror plot.

The film is perhaps best known for being the subject of a 1991 episode (["Pod People", 3x03](https://mst3k.fandom.com/wiki/MST3K_303_-_Pod_People)) of the television series [*Mystery Science Theater 3000*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_Science_Theater_3000) (commonly abbreviated as *MST3K*).  *MST3K* pokes fun at notoriously cheesy science fiction and fantasy films.

[The *MST3K* YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFzph9x-n9FR52BI94Zfgww) has a short video about this episode, including clips of the original movie and the episode's framing story:

Answer (score 3):

More details would be helpful, but this might be [*Alien Abduction: Incident in Lake County*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Abduction:_Incident_in_Lake_County) as per [movie where aliens invade a farm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95175/movie-where-aliens-invade-a-farm)

> This might be [*Alien Abduction: Incident in Lake County*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Abduction:_Incident_in_Lake_County). It aired in 1998 on UPN and was a remake of an earlier 1989 "found footage" film, *[The McPherson Tape](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/The_McPherson_Tape)*. It's not animated. It involves the McPherson family joining for Thanksgiving dinner. The descriptions have a lot of bits about the lights being out, so I assume it's at night. It does have a ray-gun, but it burns people, and involves at least two aliens.

Comment: If this answer is correct, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: My first thought as well, Alien Abduction....I wonder if OP saw the old original?

Comment: I recall watching this when it came out (the remake). It was played at the end of a "news broadcast" where the talking-heads repeatedly stated things like "you should judge whether this is real" and such, while rather obviously smirking. That and the *really* terrible acting and writing make it obviously a mockumentary. I was surprised to read people were actually confused by this, although I still find it difficult to believe.